# onChangeText is called event when editable is false

Tags: react-native, react-native-testing-library, native-testing-library

[This issue](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-testing-library/issues/476) says that `fireEvent.changeText` event should not call `onChangeText` function when `editable` is `false`, yet when I run this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { fireEvent, render } from '@testing-library/react-native';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';

describe('Button', () => {
  it('should not be editable, if editable is false', () => {
    const handleChangeText = jest.fn();
    const screen = render(<TextInput onChangeText={ handleChangeText } editable={ false } testID={ 'stuff' }/>);
    fireEvent.changeText(screen.getByTestId('stuff'), 'Trigger');
    expect(handleChangeText).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

My test fails, because `handleChangeText` is called.

I use:

1. `"@testing-library/react-native": "7.1.0"`
2. `"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.0.tar.gz"`